# Find the equations of tangents to a curve perpendicular to a given line

Tags: calculus

Find the equations of tangents to the curve  $3x^2-y^2 = 2$ which are are perpendicular to the line $x+3y=2$.

How to solve this, a clear explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any point $(x,y)$ on the curve, a perpendicular to the curve is given by
$$\nabla f(x,y)=(6x,-2y)\ .$$
The tangent is perpendicular to this direction, so you want $\nabla f$ to be in the same direction as the line.

If $(a,b)$ is a vector in the direction of the line then you want
$$\nabla f(x,y)=\alpha(a,b)$$
for some constant $\alpha$.

See if you can find $(a,b)$ and finish the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the tangent line at $x$ to the curve $y=f(x)$ is given by $f'(x)$. Two lines are perpendicular if the product of their slopes is $-1$. Combine these facts to get your answer.